# How to process and what is the use of reporting task in Nifi?

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, apache-nifi

I have gone through the below documentation link

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/developer-guide.html#reporting-tasks

But still I need a sample or workflow and its use in NiFi

Answer (score 5):

A ReportingTask is a way to push information like metrics and statistics out of NiFi to an external system. It is a global component that you define in the controller settings, similar to controller services, so it is not on the canvas.

The available reporting tasks are in the documentation below the processors:
https://nifi.apache.org/docs.html

You can also look at the examples in the NiFi code:

https://github.com/apache/nifi/tree/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-reporting-tasks

https://github.com/apache/nifi/tree/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-ambari-bundle/nifi-ambari-reporting-task

Comment: Any real time example for nifi reporting task will be useful ?

Comment: This example should be useful: https://pierrevillard.com/tag/reporting-task/